# XSLTProcessor is not defined in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform XML to XHTML. I have used XSLTProcessor in client side (Angular) and it's working fine. Now I am trying to use the same code in Node JS but it's not working and I am getting error message as XSLTProcessor undefined. Below is the client side code. Please suggest me the methods available for transformation in Node JS side.

```
transformXml(xml, xsl) {
  var html;
  if (this.isIE) {
    html = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  } else {
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    var xmlDom = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);

    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    html = serializer.serializeToString(xmlDom.documentElement);
  }

  return html;
}
```

Comment: Saxon-JS 2 runs on Node.js and is released today (12 June 2020): http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml

Answer (score 2):

`XMLTProcessor()` is not part of Node.js. You need a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt or similar - there are a number of packages for XSLT: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xslt.